# How to add one custom tickline in matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a programmatic way to force the appearance of a single tickline at the additional tick location shown below?

**Requirements:**

1. Tickline should be pointing down from x-axis
2. Tickline should extend to label 103 regardless of padding
3. Tickline should be the same color and thickness of axes
4. No changes to other ticks (ticklines or tick labels)

Code and sample image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8 / 3))
fig.tight_layout()

x_limit = 103
x = [0, 10, 50, 100, x_limit]
y = [6,  2,  5,   2,      20]

ax.plot(x, y)

# Add a tick which represents the maximum x-value
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.append(xticks, x_limit))

# Change padding of tick in the event other ticks get too close
tick = ax.get_xaxis().get_major_ticks()[-1]
tick.set_pad(14)
tick.label1 = tick._get_text1()

# Set tight axes bounds around data
ax.set_ylim(0, max(y) + 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, x_limit)
```

[image: matplotlib plot needs one more tickline]

EDIT: Tried [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949165/how-to-add-one-custom-tickline-in-maplotlib-axes/35951255#35951255)'s solution and ended up with an annotation in the right place. I do notice some aliasing as if it doesn't look like an extension of the y-axis. Any ideas on how to clean this up?

[image]

Comment: Are your tick values unpredictable?

Comment: Yes. As an example, it would be common to have the same plot with max(x) at 101, 103, 115, etc. I let matplotlib decide what integer values all the other xtick labels should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `annotate` and a bit of transform magic.

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 3), tight_layout=True)

ax.set_xlim(90, 105)

trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
tt = ax.annotate('103', (103, 0), xytext=(0, -12), transform=trans,
                 arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '-'}, ha='center', va='top',
                 textcoords='offset points')
```

[image]

Comment: This does work! I made an edit to my post to show your solution. Do you think it's possible to reduce the blur on the line so it looks like an extension of the y-axis? I played around with linewidth options with no luck.